# How to Compute Image Gradients?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, gradient

How to compute Image gradients?

In X Direction - Kernel : -1 0 1

In Y Direction - Kernel : 
-1 
0 
1

Let's assume my input image is: `unsigned char* imgImage;`

Could any one please share code. I am newbie to image processing.
Is it possible to do in OpenCV with this same kernel?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The simplest way is to make FFT of your kernel, by-pixel multiply it on image's FFT and make IFFT. But in your case, when kernel is so small, it would be better to make direct convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom kernel filter using something similar to [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html) example.

if you just want to find image gradients there are other options such as [sobel](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html) and [laplace](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/laplace_operator/laplace_operator.html)

If your aim is edge detection, I find canny is best for this in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, there is a simple function called imfilter that does this job. I am sure there is a similar function, probably with a similar name in OpenCV.